# What's the best/reliable fully opensource Ethereum wallet?

Tags: wallets, ethereum-wallet-dapp, myetherwallet

Is there any fully open-source(including the browser extension code) Ethereum wallet? I just wanted to rebrand the wallet, tweak the UI and create a new one.
Found that metamask is fully open-source but it's not MIT licensed. Trust wallet is open-source but the codebase doesn't include the browser-extension code.

Please suggest if you know any. Thanks

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another good option that is `MIT` is Liquality:

https://github.com/liquality/wallet

It's a Chrome Extension app as MetaMask.

Give it a shot!

For a desktop Ethereum wallet app, you can try `MyCrypto`, which also has the `MIT` license:

https://github.com/MyCryptoHQ/MyCrypto